# I have read a sentence in a newspaper "A coyote management program in place and have done extensive outreach.”

Tags: grammar

I have read a sentence in a [newspaper](https://abc7.com/pets-animals/culver-city-pet-owners-warning-of-coyotes-killing-cats/4080821/).

> The city manager tells Eyewitness News that they have a coyote
>   management program in place and have done extensive outreach.

But if I edit out the full grammatical sentence:

> The city manager tells Eyewitness News that they have a coyote
>   management program in place and have done **to be** extensive **to**
>   outreach **it**.

Does it still work?

Comment: Why do you think you should edit this sentence? It sounds fine to me. Your edited sentence, however, sounds awkward!

Comment: *outreach* here is a noun, not a verb.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, your edit makes no sense. It's not "full grammatical". I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Let's simplify your phrase a bit. Who have a coyote manegement program? The city council.

> The city council have a coyote management program in place and they
>   (the city council) have done extensive outreach.

**Extensive outreach** is the object of the second phrase. You can observe two elements: **extensive** (adjective) and **outreach** (noun). They represent what the city council have done.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**outreach**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outreach)

> an effort to bring services or information to people where they live
>   or spend time

**[extensive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/extensive)**

> covering a large area; having a great range

---

If we include a bit more of context from the article

> Neighbors blame city officials for not alerting the entire community.
>
> The city manager tells Eyewitness News that they have a coyote
>   management program in place and have done extensive outreach.

It means that the city council has made an effort to inform all citizens in a large area about the coyote problem and the coyote management program developed to solve that problem.

---

The city council haven't done a program to be extensive. They have done a program to control coyotes and they have done extensive outreach to inform the population about that.

Answer (score 1):

“The city manager tells Eyewitness News that they have a coyote management program in place and have done to be extensive to outreach it.” does not work.

The original sentence can be split at the *and*, and the second part

> [They] have done extensive outreach.

does not work when written as

> [They] have done to be extensive to outreach it.

What is meant is that they have done extensive outreach about the coyote management program. The original sentence *could* be written as

> "The city manager tells Eyewitness News that they have a coyote management program in place and have done extensive outreach about their coyote management program."

but this is repetitive. It is also easier to read in the shortened form, "*... done extensive outreach***.**"